# Running Robot test cases in Eclipse - Unable to find output console

Tags: eclipse, robotframework

I get an error when running my first test case with Robot Framework. I also tried choosing Console many times but nothing happened.

```
An internal error occurred during: "Launching Robot Tests".
Unable to find output console. Trying to look for a console with name:
Testsuite1.robot (Selected Test Cases) [Robot] C:\Program Files (x86)\Python38-32\python.exe
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g10gR.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably using RED? This is bug in it. See https://github.com/nokia/RED/issues/368